# Python-requests send certificate

Tags: python, python-requests

I have two files one called `public_key.pem` and another called `certificate.crt`

I extracted .cer file from browser than used

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in somefile.cer -out certificate.crt
```

then did

```
openssl x509 -inform der -pubkey -noout -in somefile.cer > public_key.pem
```

Now I am trying to pass `certificate.crt` and `public_key.pem` file to my python-requests.

```
r = requests.get('someurl.com', verify='public_key.pem', cert='certificate.crt')
```

I get the following error:`Caused by SSLError(SSLError(136, '[X509: NO_CERTIFICATE_OR_CRL_FOUND] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:4263)')))`

This is certificate.crt file

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
somecert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and this is public_key.pem

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
pubkey
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I have also tried the following:

```
response = r.get('someurl', cert=('certificate.crt','public_key.pem'), headers=headers, params=params)
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4043)')))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `verify` is used to get a non-standard certificate authority (CA) accepted by `requests`.